# Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_isSecure(Array ( ) )

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

I'm having issues with a site that has recently moved to a new host. The hosting company say it's not their issue but I'm a bit stuck for ideas.

i'm not quite sure how to post a full set of logs here but any help is appreciated!

```
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_isSecure(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/<DOMAIN>/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(42): Varien_Object->__call('_isSecure', Array)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you understand the error?

```
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_isSecure()
```

The class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` doesn't have a method `_isSecure`.

Therefore it seems like magento creates the wrong object somewhere and calls a method which doesn't exist.

Did you change the base template? I can't find any `_isSecure` call in a 1.9.1

Comment: Hi Fabian - Thanks for the prompt response :)

I'm not too familiar with this at all if I'm honest but I did try uploading a new /app/design/frontend/base directory from the latest version. This had no effect though.

How do I diagnose this further?

Comment: get a copy of your version and copy it over your installation - or diff it at least. I have no clue what the real problem is and no idea how to reproduce it

Comment: Just to say thanks again. I'm not sure what happened, but overwriting the live 'app' folder with the one from our backup solved the problem.

Comment: Hi @FabianBlechschmidt. What should I do instead of _isSecure()? My magento version in 1.9.1.0... I added action in <form> like => <?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>

Comment: as @mam08ixo linked in his post I would just copy the content of the method introduced in 1.9.2: `$this->_getApp()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure();`

Answer (score 3):

The `_isSecure` call was introduced in Magento CE 1.9.2.0.

- [view.phtml](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.0/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml#L42)
- [Mage_Core_Block_Abstract](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.0/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L1480)

As per your comment you updated the base theme but not the core files. This leads to a version mismatch (template files access block methods). Revert the theme or upgrade the Magento installation to align both.

Comment: Thanks - this makes a tiny bit of sense although I'm not sure how it happened as uploading the new base directory was a fault-finding process rather than the cause. I developed this site from scratch but it only went live recently and previous upgrades were done by creating a new site and importing the data and themes. forgive the newbie question, but is it just a matter of unzipping the contents of the newest release and overwriting the current content? or is there more to it than that? I imagine my themes should remain unaffected by doing this but I'm not 100% sure?

Comment: Actually, I've just checked the old site and it was already running 1.9.2.0 :-/

Comment: This is true, but how do we go about offering updated theme versions? Should we offer theme packages per magento version or have a magento version check inside the phtml files effected and change subjected output? Either way it seems like alot of work each time something like this occurs...                                       if(magento version equals 1.9.2.0) {$submit = $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())); }else{ $submit = ''older version submit action'; }