# Best way to provide themes as per magento updates

Tags: theme, upgrade

I am developing a custom theme (built off 1.9.0.1, i know older version already) and have a few phtml overrides via local.xml but as per comment at [Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_isSecure(Array ( ) )](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83200/invalid-method-mage-catalog-block-product-view-issecurearray) what is the best way to provide custom themes that don't conflict with magento versions, see below;

- Supply Theme package for each magento version (specify magento version supported)
- One theme package with a version check (in the phtml file(s)) as per conflicts when mismatched
- or another way to manage theme updating/changes

Is there access to public list of edited/updated/compared files per magento version as obviously it would be a nightmare to check each file for different code

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 1, you can use this inofficial mirror on GitHub: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/

Then use `git diff` or your favorite Git client to view changes. Unfortunately for each release, the "copyright" notice in **all** files changes, so you probably want to exclude these:

```
git difftool -y -x "diff -I '-I '@license .*' -I '@copyright *Copyright .* Inc''" <commit1> <commit2>
```

where `<commit1>` and `<commit2>` are commit references for the versions you want to compare:

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/commits/magento-1.9